# How do I make isolated dalvik

Tags: android, linux, virtual-machine, dalvik, dex

I am tracing the Dalvik machine source code. According that, I want to make Dalvik runnable. I have seem the dvk project. But there has many problem result in fault. Are there have any way to make dalvik only without all android. Because make android will take too much time (about many hour)

dvk project: http://code.google.com/p/dvk/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compile Dalvik to run it locally on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542268/how-can-i-compile-dalvik-to-run-it-locally-on-linux)

Answer (score 5):

if you build the lunch "sim-eng", you get a dalvikvm built for just the host (i.e. the Linux box you're building on). this already runs with glibc rather than bionic.

if you want to build for a device, and just want a quicker build, you don't need to rebuild everything; "mmm dalvik snod" should be sufficient. (though if you haven't changed anything in dalvik/libcore/, just making changes to the VM shouldn't rebuild much anyway, even if you do a full top-level "make".)

and don't forget to use "make -j" to get some parallelism into your build!

Comment: The `mmm' command works great for me. I'm wondering how I can get to know such commands.

Comment: I'm not on VPN at the moment, but iirc "make help" is useful. You might also want to just wade through the build/envsetup.sh stuff. Personally, though, I don't use much beyond "make" for a full build and "mmm dalvik libcore snod" when I've only touched dalvik or libcore. There are "m" and "mm" too, but I can never remember what they do!

Comment: I can't find "sim-eng" target in android branch I've synced. Could you provide branch name with "sim-eng" target?

Answer (score 0):

This [GitHub project](https://github.com/reyammer/dexware/tree/master/dalvik/linux-x86/bin) has a pre-compiled binary of Dalvik VM for Linux, ready to use! Check the associated [blog post](http://reyammer.blogspot.com/2013/12/the-behind-scene-of-dexware-dalvikvm.html) for information about how the binary was compiled and how to use it.